# C++ list iterator not accessing content of list

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, stdlist

***Visualization***:
**NTlist**: [ NTstring, RHSlist ]<-->[ NTstring, RHSlist ]<-->[ NTstring, RHSlist ]...

**Ntlocation** "points" to, say ,middle link **^** (above) because NTstring here matches what I am searching for.

***What I want to do:***
Using **NTlocation** "pointer" I want to access and modify the RHSlist here.

***The problem:***
[Debugger shows RHSlist data being put into NTlocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TINeC.png)

[But I want RHSlist data to be in element of NTlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH3Vr.png)

Thanks so much for your assistance!

EDIT. added code per request.  Thanks again!

```
typedef struct RHSnode {
  token_type type;
  string token;
} RHSnode;

typedef struct NTnode {
  token_type type;
  string token;
  list<RHSnode> RHSlist;
} NTnode;

int function {
  list<NTnode> NTlist;
  list<NTnode>::iterator NTlocation;

  freopen("example.txt", "r", stdin);
  t_type = getToken(); //this function gets tokens from txt file above
  // code has been simplified for your viewing pleasure
  // but basically NT.list is created for each token listed at start of 
  // text file in the following manner.  (This works fine)
  NTnode entry;
  entry.token = string(current_token);
  NTlist.push_back(entry);
  t_type = getToken();

  // loop until all tokens are read 
  {
    t_type = getToken(); 
    string NTstring = string(current_token);
    NTlocation = searchNTList(NTstring, NTlist);

    RHSnode entry;
    entry.token = string(current_token);

    //****Here is the problem:
    NTlocation->RHSlist.push_back(entry);            

  }

  return 1;
}

list<NTnode>::iterator searchNTList(string NTstring, list<NTnode> &NTlist){
  list<NTnode>::iterator NTlocation = NTlist.end(); //"past-the-end"     indications search failure
  list<NTnode>::iterator iterator = NTlist.begin();

  for ( ; iterator != NTlist.end() ; iterator++ ){

    if (iterator->token.compare(NTstring) == 0){
      NTlocation = iterator;
      break; 
    }

  }
  return NTlocation;
}
```

Comment: Show code, prose is all vain!

Comment: You've also got a large amount of code in your question. Is all of it necessary for your question? Could you reduce it down to the smallest amount that still reproduces your problem?

Comment: @BillLynch Thanks for looking at the code.  It has been simplified.  Much respect to you, sir.

Comment: also @πάνταῥεῖ, I've added simplified code and debugger images.  Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help you

Answer (score 1):

At the very least:

```
list<NTnode>::iterator searchNTList(string NTstring, list<NTnode> NTlist){
```

This returns an iterator to the local copy of `NTlist`. You probably want to pass `NTlist` by const reference.